# SQL statement fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-order-by

I use this statement:

```
  SELECT ThreadsID
    FROM Threads 
ORDER BY ThreadsID DESC
```

Why does the sql statement fail to return what I'd expect?  For some reason, it puts one record with an `id = 32` between `id = 52` and `id = 53`:

```
threadid
---------
...
53
32  -- <-- huh?!
52
```

Connection string:

```
    <add name="modelConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite10\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /
```

I have got additional info that effects the list:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("SELECT u.Name,t.ThreadTitle,t.Date, t.Views,t.Replies,p.Theme,p.Topics,t.PageNumber, t.ThreadsID");
    sb.Append("  FROM Threads AS t");
    sb.Append( " INNER JOIN Users AS u ON u.UsersID=t.UsersID");
    sb.Append( " INNER JOIN Topics AS p ON p.TopicsID=t.TopicsID");
    sb.Append(" WHERE t.ThreadsID=@ThreadsID");
```

The @ThreadsID..goes to the second query...But it doesnt effect the order of things.. after both of those seperate sql commands get executed i get the weird result that i get

Comment: are you sorting by ThreadsID or by id ?

Comment: Is id same as ThreadsID in your example?

Comment: For what database, and please post the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the `THREADS` table.  Initial assumption is that `threadid` is not a numeric data type.

Comment: @OMG ditto on the assumption; I'm thinking text-based with leading padding on half the values

Comment: @Dmitry and the db is? Also, the output shown is not 100%  consistent with the query - can we assume nothing got garbled in the copy/paste?

Comment: the database, was the one i created in visual studio 2010. here is teh connection string....above.. I keep pressing again and again..and the list shows 32 between 53 52

Comment: @MarcGravell let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1087/discussion-between-dmitry-makovetskiyd-and-marc-gravell)

Comment: @Dmitry sure; going to join us?

Answer (score 0):

It could be because Id is not a number type. What kind of data is threadId on your table?

Comment: this is not answer this is question

Comment: The answer is that it could be because Id is not a number type. It  has an additional question yes

Comment: @Senad oh, I'm pretty sure it *is* the answer, and (comments on question) I'm not alone in that suspicion. As an *answer* it is in that tricky grey area between "comment" and "answer", I'll agree.

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd Is the stringbuilder the actual statement that is being executed?, the statement does not have an order by clause.

Comment: No it is a separate statement.. i used to have a order by clause..it messed things up..But i removed it.. The situation improved..But i keep seeing that glitch.. i also used ctrl+f to seek for any other sqlcommand manipulation in the code files/pages..and i found nothing